# MPMoviePlayerController freezes if background audio is active

Tags: ios, audio, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

In a view controller I have a video playing and also some background music. If the background music is playing, the video freezes when it goes to loop. If the background music is not playing the video loops normally as it should.

Here's how I'm setting up the video player:

```
self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[self getBundleClip:@"MyVideo"]];
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
```

The audio is playing via this [Sound Manager](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager). Any idea why the video would be freezing?

Comment: did u want to play music background and play video in repeat mode?

Comment: Yes, that's why I have self.moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

Answer (score 0):

Try to use play music in background `AVAudioPlayer` and play same time `MPMoviePlayerController` like below code for play the AVAudioplayer in repeat mode:

first initialize the AVAudioplayer object in your header file (.h) like below:

```
@interface  Yourviewcontroller : UIViewController
{
    //your some codes after
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

after implement play audio file in background like below code:

```
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:    [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"audio" ofType:@"mp3"]] error:NULL]; 

    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops =-1;//it's play audio repeatedly
    audioPlayer.currentTime=0.0f;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

after play audio any part of project like below code:

```
  [audioPlayer play];
```

you want stop the audio player like below code:

```
 [audioPlayer stop];
```